# Pyqt application using matplotlib plots strange behavior when used in a different monitor

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm creating a Pyqt application where i want to plot an empty figure when the application is loaded, and then plot some data every time a button is pressed.

Here is my current minumum working example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1126, 568)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButtonConnect = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Connect")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonConnect, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonConnect.clicked.connect(self.runGraph)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

    def runGraph(self):
        canvas_new = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
        plt.plot([random(), random()], [random(), random()])
        self.gridLayout.replaceWidget(self.canvas, canvas_new)
        self.canvas = canvas_new


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Which gives an application that, after 5 button clicks
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI3ov.png).

However if a open the same application on my laptop screen (rather than in my external monitor), every time I click the button every line get bigger, and after 5 clicks
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldHbw.png).

And even more: If I try to resize the main Window with:

```py
self.resize(1126, 568)
```

on my monitor [looks normal after 5 clicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rf7q.png), but on my laptop screen [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQWB2.png), like it's resizing the grid if I click the button.

I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug of matplotlib+Pyqt?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: See [Embedding in Qt](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html). You should create one ```FigureCanvas``` for one ```Figure```. Use ```self.canvas.draw()``` to update the canvas.

Comment: @relent95 Thanks a lot, it does perfectly the job and fix the problem! The mystery of why my laptop screen works like that will stay unsolved. PS: if you write down your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: What about answering your own question? It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As relent95 suggested in the comment, simply using `self.canvas.draw()` does the job and fix the issue.
So now the function is:

```
def runGraph(self):
    plt.plot([random(), random()], [random(), random()])
    self.canvas.draw()
```

On the other hand, the mystery of my laptop strange behaviour will stay unsolved.